# Changing style of file browse button (MyFaces inputFileUpload)

Tags: javascript, css, file-upload

my task is to implement a CSS style to a submit button of a file upload widget. I decided to make an original widget invisible and to add text field and button which are visible and have the styles I need and can use a functionality of the original widget.

```
<t:inputFileUpload id="fileupload" style="display:none" value="#{Handler.upFile}" accept="application/pdf,image   /tiff"    onchange="Handlechange();"/>                    

<input type="text" id="filename" class="input400px"  readonly = "readonly"/> 
<input type="button" id="fakeBrowse" class="browseButton" value="Browse..." onclick="HandleBrowseClick();"/>

function HandleBrowseClick()
{
    var fileinput = document.getElementById("uploadForm:fileupload");
    fileinput.click();
}

function Handlechange()
{

var fileinput = document.getElementById("uploadForm:fileupload");
var textinput = document.getElementById("filename"); 
textinput.value = fileinput.value;

}
```

It works in Firefox, but not in IE. I suppose that click() doesn't work properly in IE. Has anyone ideas how I can solve a problem for IE and why it doesn't work there? Thank you.